# Ekko lightbox closes popup on escape button push

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I cannot find the way lightbox popup window is closed when user pushes escape button.

No such event handler in lightbox.js file.

Somebody can explain the way lightbox closes the popup?

Comment: Are you using some library for this: ? maybe: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/

Comment: @mitogh this: https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely forgot that ekko ligthbox is connected to bootstrap, so the behavior was going from bootstrap.js.

Line #1062 if somebody has the same question as mine.